# Select the minimum value comparing two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare two columns and get the minimum value but ignore zeros, except when they're both zero.

Table contents:

```
Id  Unit value  Unit Ext value
1       0       12
2       15      10
3       8       25
4       15      15
5       0       0
6       4       0
7       Null    Null
```

Desired result

```
Id  Unit value  Unit Ext value  min value
1       0           12              12
2       15          10              10
3       8           25              8
4       15          15              15
5       0           0               0
6       4           0               4
7       Null        Null            Null
```

My query:

```
case when unitvalue<Unit Ext value  then Unit value
     when unitvalue>Unit Ext then Unit Ext value 
end min value
```

But my result has min value 0 for id's 1 and 6.

Comment: and why are you not happy with case-statement ?

Comment: It is giving zero, but I don't want a zero value (id number: 1 and 6)

Comment: In SQL Server 2022 you'd use [least()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql) otherwise you can use `iif` if you don't like a case expression

Comment: what will you do for rows 5 and 7 where everything is 0, or everything is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression should provide the desired result

```
case when unit_value < Unit_Ext_value and unit_value > 0 
  then Unit_value 
else
  case when Unit_Ext_Value = 0 
    then Unit_Value 
    else Unit_Ext_Value 
  end
end
```

Comment: You can remove the inner case statement and move its contents into the outer case

Answer (score 0):

Handle the edge cases first:

```
select
  id,
  unit_value,
  unit_ext_value,
  case
    when unit_value = 0 and unit_ext_value = 0 then 0
    when unit_value = 0 or unit_value is null then unit_ext_value
    when unit_ext_value = 0 or unit_ext_value is null then unit_value
    else least(unit_value, unit_ext_value)
  end as min_value
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Check if at least one of the columns is 0.

If yes, use `GREATEST`, else use `LEAST`:

```
SELECT
  id, unit_value, unit_ext_value,
  CASE WHEN 0 IN (unit_value, unit_ext_value)
    THEN GREATEST(unit_value, unit_ext_value) 
    ELSE LEAST(unit_value, unit_ext_value) END AS min_value
FROM yourtable;
```

See this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kE282suL)

Comment: You could shorten that a bit to `isnull(least(nullif(unit_value, 0), nullif(unit_ext_value, 0)), 0) min_value`